# Windows Emacs 25.3 Cursor Type

Tags: emacs

I have issue changing `cursor-type` in Emacs 25.3 and 25.2 on Windows. Picture is worth thousand words, so here it is

[image]

No customization whatsoever.

I try to change `cursor-type` to a `box` directly or via frame parameters and it is always a `bar`. Even when `cursor-type` is set to `t` it is a `bar`
Is there a way to change it ?

Comment: What happens if you type `M-x eval-expression RET (setq cursor-type 'box) RET`

Comment: Nothing happens to a cursor, that is for sure. I tried `setq`, `setq-default`, `set-default`, I tried also both `default-cursor-type` and `cursor-type` as well as changing it through `default-frame-alist` parameters.The issue most likely is OS specific, because on Fedora Linux it is a `box`

Comment: Emacs for Windows (GUI version) should work correctly with cursors out of the box.  Perhaps the installation is broken.  `w32term.c` (internal components of Emacs) extends all cursor types to Emacs for Windows (GUI version) installations.  Consider trying a different build or building your own from source.

Comment: Do you see the same problem when you start Emacs using `emacs -Q` and in other modes, in addition to the mode you show here? If not, then bisect your init file to find the culprit.

Comment: @Drew The picture is of emacs started with `-Q`. No customization. The cursor is bar in all of the windows and modes as far as I can tell.

Comment: I don't see that, in Emacs 25.3.1 (and other releases), with `emacs -Q`, on MS Windows. `M-: (setq cursor-type 'box)` or whatever, works fine. Consider filing a bug report: `M-x report-emacs-bug`. Keep in mind that `cursor-type` is buffer-local, so you must set it in the individual buffer (or set its default and hope that something local doesn't override that setting).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It looks like `w32-use-visible-system-caret` is non-nil.  This can happen by default if Emacs detects some application is using the Accessibility API to track the position of the cursor - most commonly screen readers, and screen magnifiers.  Such software often relies on the default Windows cursor being used and visible, rather than the customizable internal Emacs implementation of a cursor.

You can manually force this variable to `nil` in your startup files if you wish to continue using whatever software is triggering this, but have Emacs use its own cursor drawing.  The other software may not work well with Emacs in that case however.

Comment: That's the answer. Once I set `w32-use-visible-system-caret` to `nil` it went back to normal. The application in question seems to be `Windows Speech Recognition`. If emacs starts when this application is running then I get this effect on the cursor.

Comment: @EvgeniySharapov, I think for me it was also Speech Recognition.
I enabled it because it allows voice commands with a Flight Simulator Addon I use. 
At some point I notices the cursor change, and I would have never linked the two...